# add Count values (for loop)

Tags: c#, for-loop, count

i have this problem, i am supposed to write code and check for divisibility of the numbers in the array, with numbers (goodValue, and badValue).. if good and bad value are divisible by the number in the array, we add +2 , if the number is divisible by good value, we add +1, and if the value is divisible by only badValue we subtract 1.

```
public class Array {
    static int[] ArrayA ={8, 4, 3, 12, 7, 9};
    static int[] ArrayB ={3, 8, 14, 12, 10, 16, 6};
    static int score;

public static void main(String [] args){

    score = scoreArray(ArrayA, 2, 3);
    System.out.println("First score for arrayA: " + score);
    score = scoreArray(ArrayA, 3, 4);
    System.out.println("Second score for ArrayA: " +score);
    score = scoreArray(ArrayB, 5, 2);
    System.out.println("First score for ArrayB: " +score);
    score = scoreArray(ArrayB, 3, 7);
    System.out.println("Second score for ArrayB: " +score);


}

private static int scoreArray( int [] theArray, int goodValue, int badValue){
    for (int i=0; i<=theArray.length; i++){
        if((i%goodValue & i%badValue)==0){
            score=+2;               
        }
        else if (i%goodValue==0){
            score=+1;
        }
        else if((i%badValue==0)){
            score= -1;
        }
        score+=score;
    }

    return score;

    }
}
```

i am supposed to get this

```
Firts score for arrayA: 1
Second score for arrayA: 3
First sccore for arrayB: -3
Second score for ArrayB: 2
```

and i am getting this

```
First score for arrayA: 2
Second score for ArrayA: 2
First score for ArrayB: 2
Second score for ArrayB: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that your typed wrongly ....

```
score=+2;
```

should be

```
score += 2;
```

Similarly in other else statements it should be

```
score += 1;
```

and

```
score -=1;
```

I think I am not completely understanding the wording you mentioned in your problem. You are using number in one place and value in another and this is confusing me.

I have improved the score calculation logic, but not giving the exact answer you expect

```
private static int scoreArray( int [] theArray, int goodValue, int badValue){
            score = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
        if(((theArray[i]%goodValue)==0) && ((theArray[i]%badValue)==0)){
            score += 2;             
        }
        else if (theArray[i]%goodValue==0){
            score+=1;
        }
        else if((theArray[i]%badValue==0)){
            score -= 1;
        }
    }
    return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't give me the right answers. i cant figure out whats wrong. is it the for loop or any of the statements?

Comment: I have updated the answer ... but I am getting confused to some level with wording of problem -  if the number is divisible by good value, we add +1, and if the value is divisible by only badValue we subtract 1.  --- what do you mean by value in Last statement.

Comment: @Guille I have updated the answer. Now the problem is simpler. You were Dividing "i" by goodvalue or badvalue, instead you should us theArray[i]. Also the answer you expect is not correct. it should be 2, 2, -3, 2

Comment: ok, now i kind of got this thing working.. but it wont give me the result of the (First score ArrayB) it gives me 0, instead of -3. the other answers are the correct ones.

Comment: @Guille, sorry one more issue is you are using static score, so when it goes into calculation of score second time it starts with score = 2 and not 0 and so on. You need to reset score to 0 in every loop or else make score local variable in both the functions.

Comment: i got it working now(kind of).. it give me 1, 3, 0, 2  instead of 1, 3, -3, 2.. its like if the if it is not adding.

Comment: You still have score = +2; and also you are not resetting value of score. --- Sorry my mistake .. i had that in the code... corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Array 
{
static int[] ArrayA ={8, 4, 3, 12, 7, 9};
static int[] ArrayB ={3, 8, 14, 12, 10, 16, 6};
static int score=0;

public static void main(String [] args)
{

score = scoreArray(ArrayA, 2, 3);
System.out.println("First score for arrayA: " + score);
score = scoreArray(ArrayA, 3, 4);
System.out.println("Second score for ArrayA: " +score);
score = scoreArray(ArrayB, 5, 2);
System.out.println("First score for ArrayB: " +score);
score = scoreArray(ArrayB, 3, 7);
System.out.println("Second score for ArrayB: " +score);


}

public static int scoreArray( int [] theArray, int goodValue, int badValue)
{    score =0;
for (int i=0; i<theArray.length; i++)
{

 if(((theArray[i]%goodValue)==0) && ((theArray[i]%badValue)==0))
  {

      score = score+2;           

  }
   else if (theArray[i]%goodValue==0)
    {
       score = score+1;   
    }
    else if((theArray[i]%badValue==0))
    {
       score = score+(-1);  
    }



}
return score;
 }
  }
```

it will work fine as per your requirement...if any issues post your comments.

```
  output
  First score for arrayA: 2   
  Second score for ArrayA: 2
  First score for ArrayB: -3
  Second score for ArrayB: 2
```